# my code won't compile

Tags: c++

i get an error "missing ; before identifier".

no ; is missing.

this error appears only when i include one of the files:
MAPIDefS.h
Windows.h
wtypes.h
WinBase.h

what could be the problem?

Thanks a whole lot.  I tried everything everybody suggested and it worked.  The problem was I used a name in my file which was also defined in these header files.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the code that produces this,  and the full error message VC++ gave you

Comment: Post the source code near the compiler error.

Comment: Please provide your relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in MAPIDefS.h, Windows.h, wtypes.h, or WinBase.h

Comment: @Falmarri - those header files are used in millions of apps.  The problem is in OP's code or its use of the header files, or OP's build options, not the header files themselves.

Comment: The error is on line 42 of your code.

Comment: You might be trying to use a name that's defined as a macro in windows.h, but without the code I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Steve: I was being sarcastic, since that was the only information we got.

Comment: @Falmarri: Sarcasm does not translate to text (as much of it is implied through tonal use of the language). In text form you need to provide additional feedback (that replaces the tone). ;-) <-Smiley face helps to indicate your intentions on being sarcastic>

Answer (score 2):

All of these include files, except for `MAPIDefs.h`, are already included by `Windows.h`.
Manually including them will cause obscure errors.

You should remove all of the includes except for `Windows.h` and `MAPIDefs.h`.

Comment: just compiled with the include files as in the  question ,no errors !

Answer (score 1):

Check the file which includes that header file, or any previous includes. Sometimes the error may propagate from previous files.

The most common mistake which gives such strange errors is omitting the semicolon `;` after a class definition in one  of the headers.

That's all I can say without seeing any code, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

include windows.h before other windows api files.

If you have other include files or #define statements before the windows api files then you probably have define a symbol that is used in the API files. You should check that.

Comment: No; don't include the others at all